# Make WordPress show the same page on two different url patterns

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

I need to make WordPress show the same page on two different URLs:

```
https://sitename.com/%postname%/
https://sitename.com/%postname%/tail/
```

** I can only use functions.php*

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Already been answered, here is one - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183927/76745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a few similar cases and guides and here is code which worked out for me:

```
function tail_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/tail?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top');
    // first parameter for posts: p or name, for pages: page_id or pagename
}

add_action('init', 'tail_rewrite');
```

> don't forget to flush the rules by visiting Settings > Permalinks
>       OR use flush_rewrite_rules() in the plugin activation (don't execute it at every page load).